# SQL Always Returns that a record exisits (MYSQLI, PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

The code below is supposed to Check if a user exists in the data base but when run the query always returns true.

CODE:

```
function checkifexists($username, $email){

    require __DIR__ . '/includes/dbcon.php';

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? or `email` = ?");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
    $query->execute();
    if(!$query->num_rows){

        //User or Email Already Exists.
        $query->close();
        //header("Location: Register?error=inuse");
        echo "inuse";
        die();
    }
    else {
        var_dump($query);
        $query->close();
        regacc();
    }

}
```

How do I make it check if a user exists or not; correctly.

Any Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`mysqli_stmt::store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) before your call to `$query->num_rows`. Right now it's not using the correct result set, so it always returns 0, so `!0` is always true.

> You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query that successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN), if and only if you want to buffer the complete result set by the client, so that the subsequent mysqli_stmt_fetch() call returns buffered data.

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? or `email` = ?");
$query->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
if(!$query->num_rows) {
```

As a side note, try being clearer with the intention of your code here. Use `if($query->num_rows > 0)` rather than relying on the "truthiness" of the value.